# How to discontinue service if mobile app is out of date?

Tags: react-native, versioning

I'm working on a react-native app, and want to have the ability for us have the following workflow:

1. A user running an old version of the app starts it up
2. They see a screen saying their current version is out of date.  It has an "Update now" button and a "Close App" button.

It would be ideal if we can control which versions are considered out of date that this message will display on.

Are there any libraries or services that streamline this app versioning / whitelisting process?

Ideally this will work for both Android and iOS

Comment: Maybe create a web call at the beginning of the app that return you if the app is updated or don't. And then if the app isn't Alert the message that is not updated ?